# 'ls $variable' does not list folder contents

Tags: bash

I have created a simple script to list the contents in a bunch of folders. The folder list has been extracted from a database and all exists in the system.

```
listOfFolders='/home/jca/List_of_folders.csv'

for folder in `cat $listOfFolders`
do
    a=`expr substr $folder 1 2`
    b=`expr substr $folder 3 2`
    AbsolutePath=`printf $a'/'$b'/'$folder`
    echo  $AbsolutePath
#   ls $AbsolutePath
done
```

If I run the script like that I get the correct path to each folder I want to `ls` like this:

```
37/88/37886
38/28/38284
38/35/38359
15/74/15746
38/78/38789
38/79/38793
38/93/38934
38/93/38937
38/94/38941
39/17/39173
40/38/40380
39/36/39364
39/75/39752
39/83/39832
39/91/39910
```

If I randomly pick up one line and do an `ls` and I get all the contents of the folder as expected.

When I comment the `echo $AbsolutePath` and uncomment the `ls $AbsolutePath` I get a list of errors:

```
: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
```

I am pretty sure that it is the correct directory because when I perform the `ls 39/91/39910` in the shell I get the expected result.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: isn't there whitespaces? maybe an export before the assignment could help.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.

The problem was the Carriage return. As Alfe mentioned the (printf "[%q]\n" "$AbsolutePath") helped me to find out that there was one '\r' after each string.

This is the resulting code after fixing it:

for folder in `cat $listOfFolders`
        do
        a=`expr substr $folder 1 2`
        b=`expr substr $folder 3 2`
        AbsolutePath=`printf $a'/'$b'/'${folder//$'\r'/}`
#       printf "[%q]\n" "${AbsolutePath//$'\r'/}"
#       echo  $AbsolutePath
        ls "$AbsolutePath"
        done
#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your experience is weird, probably you mistook something.  If the output with the `echo` is as you post it, the output of the `ls` should not be error messages about empty strings (starting with a colon).

It might help you to debug your stuff using this:

```
printf "[%q]\n" "$AbsolutePath"
```

instead of the simple echo.  Mind the quotes!  They are important.  When using the value of a variable almost always you should use double quotes, otherwise spaces and other nasty characters in the value have (mostly) unwanted effects.  So better try this:

```
ls "$AbsolutePath"
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I can now see what the problem is:[$'40/38/40380\r']
[$'39/36/39364\r']
[$'39/75/39752\r']
[$'39/83/39832\r']
Probably i need to get rid of the '\r' return Char

Answer (score 0):

`'ls $AbsolutePath'` and `"ls $AbsolutePath"` is not the same , inside the  `' '` the $ symbol has not any power

Comment: I think you were just fooled by OP's bad formatting.  I fixed that by now.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your prompt answer. What you say it is totally true but did not have any effect in the script. When i try 'ls $AbsolutePath' as you mentioned the variable is ignored and output as plain text and "ls $AbsolutePath" produces the same error.

Comment: @user2833683, Oh like Alfe said i was fooled by the question's title ,you  have the 'ls $blabla' inside '' ...